# Find $k$ if given the constant term of a binomial expression?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Consider the expansion of $x^2(3x^2+\frac{k}{x})^8$. The constant term is $16,128$. Find $k$.

This is simply an example of a type of question I cannot understand how to do. I have many questions:

1) What is a *constant term* in regards to binomials?

2) How would I go about solving this?

3) How can I check that my solution is correct?

4) How would I be able to *find* the constant term if asked to do so?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant term is just the coefficient of $x^0$; it's just like the constant term of a polynomial. So to find the constant term, you want to figure out what is the coefficient of the term in $(3x^2 + \frac{k}{x})^8$ corresponding to $x^{-2}$, since this will cancel the $x^2$ to produce a constant. To do that, you can expand $(3x^2 + \frac{k}{x})^8$ using the binomial theorem.

Comment: the other answers were too complicated for me to understand. this one made it a bit easier. i didnt use the binomial theorem per se but i figured it out and got the right answer thanks to you. so thanks

Answer (score 0):

The constant term in $x^2(3x^2+\frac{k}{x})^8$ is the term in the expansion that does not have any $x$ factor. Let's use the binomial theorem to expand this out to find the term without the $x$ factor.

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{8}\binom{8}{i}(3x^2)^{i}(\frac{k}{x})^{8-i}&=\sum_{i=0}^{8}\binom{8}{i}3^{i}k^{8-i}\frac{x^{2i}x^{2}}{x^{8-i}}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{8}\binom{8}{i}3^{i}k^{8-i}x^{2i+2-8+i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{8}\binom{8}{i}3^{i}k^{8-i}x^{3i-6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, $x^{3i-6}=x^{0}\iff i = 2$. This tells us that the constant term is:

$$
\binom{8}{2}3^{2}k^{6}=\frac{8!}{2!6!}\cdot 9k^{6}=28\cdot 9 k^{6}=252k^6.
$$

Now, we solve for $k$:

$$
252k^6=16128\implies k^6=64\implies k=2 , -2
$$

Comment: hi! can you explain the part with the sigmas? i cant quite see how you got the answer from that, nor do i understand why/how you changed the equation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the binomial theorem?

Comment: yes but your explanation is a bit confusing to me. can you please explain how you got from the very first show of the binomial theorem(where the formula has just been input into the theorem with no re-arranging of the formula) to the last one where 3ik8−ix3i−6? thank you

Comment: It is just a matter of applying the following rules of exponentiation: $z^{a+b}=z^{a}\cdot z^{b}$, $z^{-a}=\frac{1}{z^{a}}$, and $(z^{a})^{b}=z^{ab}$.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of getting your head round the problem is to rewrite it.

You are being asked about the coefficient of $x^0$ in the binomial expansion of $x^2(3x^2+\frac{k}{x})^8$.

Multiply the expression inside the parentheses by $x$ and divide the expression outside the parentheses by $x^8$ (the 8th power is because the expression inside the parentheses is being raised to the 8th power):

$$x^2(3x^2+\frac{k}{x})^8 \equiv \frac{x^2}{x^8}(3x^3+k)^8$$

So you are being asked about the coefficient of $x^0$ in $x^{-6}(3x^3+k)^8$.

Or, equivalently, about the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(3x^3+k)^8$.

At which point, this should look like the kind of binomial problem you are familiar with. I don't want to spoil it for you by giving the answer.